# Why is the background flashing/flickering when transitioning to another image? css animation keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, slideshow, keyframe

The background is supposed to be a automatic slideshow of different images. However, when it transitions to the next image, there is a white flash/flick. Am I doing something wrong? I'm using keyframes in css

```
html,body{
  animation-name: rainbowtext;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes rainbowtext{
  0%{
    background-image: url("diet-soda.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
  }
  25%{
    background-image: url("coke.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50%{
    background-image: url("diet-soda2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
  }
  75%{
    background-image: url("soda2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100%{
    background-image: url("sugar.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: simply because the image are not loaded so this happen in the first iteration and then it will disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Temani Afif already said, your problem comes from the loading time from the server.

Preload your images using them for the previous keyframe, even though they aren't visible:

```
html,body{
  animation-name: rainbowtext;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}


@keyframes rainbowtext{
  0%{
    background-image: url("diet-soda.jpg"), url("coke.jpeg");
  }
  25%{
    background-image: url("coke.jpeg"), url("diet-soda2.jpg");
  }
  50%{
    background-image: url("diet-soda2.jpg"), url("soda2.jpg");
  }
  75%{
    background-image: url("soda2.jpg"), url("sugar.jpeg");
  }
  100%{
    background-image: url("sugar.jpeg");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change only `background-image` inside the keyframe...The problem is body has `0` height by default and you are applying `height` inside keyframe

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  animation-name: rainbowtext;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes rainbowtext {
  0% {
    background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports");
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2");
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4");
  }
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: the height has nothing to do here, the background will be propagated to the canvas and will cover the whole screen even if the body and html both have 0 height ... am sure he's talking about the time needed to load the image from the server so while waiting he see some white